# I am using an IFrame and WebView to display YouTube video. The video quality is always large. How to make it play higher quality video?

Tags: android, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I already tried the setPlaybackQuality() function, doesn't work. I also tried set diffirent dimension of the video, doesn't work either. The internet speed is good.I t should has no problem to load a hd1080 quality. But the video quality is always large, never change. Any help is appraciated.

Comment: To get you started, follow the html link provided in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player). Check your browser if it meets the [requirements](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements).

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I had already completed what you said. I tried the html file on my android webview, the resolution is alway large rather than hd720. But when I tried the html on my browser, the resolution is hd720. I don't know why.